# How to add attribute to HTML element using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Using javascript (preferably not jquery) I'm trying to change the line:

```
<input type="number" name="price" required="" id="id_price">
```

into

```
<input type="number" name="price" required="" id="id_price" step="any">
```

I know the solution's got to be easy but I just can't crack it. Help would be much appreciated!!

Comment: Are you trying to write a function that transforms HTML strings, or that modifies the DOM?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

As ***torazaburo*** suggests in the comment you can do it in one step with `setAttribute()` method

```js
document.getElementById("id_price").setAttribute("step","any");
```

```html
<input type="number" name="price" required="" id="id_price">
```

---

**OR**

First create the attribute and set the value. Then add it to the element..

```js
var attr = document.createAttribute('step');
attr.value="any";
document.getElementById("id_price").setAttributeNode(attr);
```

```html
<input type="number" name="price" required="" id="id_price">
```

Comment: This is an unnecessarily wordy way to simply do `setAttribute`.