# How to download a image on link click instead of opening it

Tags: javascript, html, flask

I am running a flask app, and using a plugin named "Autoindex" for listing all the files in a directory, 
[like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O2WMW.png)
Now, when i click on an image name, it opens the image. But I want to downlaod the image without leaving the page on button click.

I cannot modify the `HTML` code of this. So I was thinking, can i use Javascript to perform this task?

**EDIT**

This is the HTML CODE:

```
<td class="name">
  <a href="/templete/images/2.jpg">2.jpg</a></td>
<td class="modified">
  <time datetime="2019-07-15 15:42:20.989829">2019-07-15 15:42:20.989829</time>
</td>
<td class="size">
```

Now, I cannot modify the HTML Code directly. The link has no class, how can I change  this

```
<a href="/templete/images/2.jpg">2.jpg</a>
```

to this, for all image links in the page.

```
<a href="" download="/templete/images/2.jpg">2.jpg</a>
```

Comment: just add `target="_blank"` to your `<img/>` tag then it will be opened in new tab. Not exactly what you need but at least user has the choice to download it or not.

Comment: I don't want to give choice, i want user to download. I got an idea, I can use javascript to ad "download" attribute. Like `<a href="dsfsf.jpg" download>link</a>

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Force browser to download image files on click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17527713/force-browser-to-download-image-files-on-click)

Comment: `This is not a duplicate question.` That's a bold assertion, literally... :)

Comment: The solution you're looking for is to add the `download` attribute. This solution is the top answer. The fact that you have to add the attribute using JS is just an implementation detail. If your actual question is "how do I add an attribute to an element using JS" then I'll mark it as dupe of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27466969/how-to-add-attribute-to-html-element-using-javascript)

Comment: If this solution doesn't work, the other possibility is to change the links' `href` to a different URL and create a flask endpoint that sends the image as [download](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Disposition).

Comment: Understood, thanks a lot @ChrisG . I modified the question. I have one problem, how do I select the element, see the updated question please.

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll(".name a").forEach(a => a.setAttribute('download', ''));` (just add the download attribute, keep the `href` as it is)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use JS to add download attribute to a HTML element:

```
element.setAttribute('download','')
```

Or even simpler:

```
element.download=''
```

So, you can easily add this for each link with a `href` ending `.jpg`:

```
const links=document.querySelectorAll('a[href$=".jpg"]')
links.forEach(link=>link.download='')
```

Comment: Sorry for wasting your time. How do  I select the element, if I do not have any class in link attribute?

Comment: My answer already does it: `const links=document.querySelectorAll('a[href$=.jpg]')` selects all `<a>` elements with `href` attribute ending with `.jpg`

Comment: Got this error `Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'querySelectorAll' on 'Document': 'a[href$=.jpg]' is not a valid selector.`

Comment: @JohnDoe You need `document.querySelectorAll('[href$=".jpg"], [href$=".png"]')`

Comment: Thanks a lot Chris G, u r god

Comment: please don't automatically approve *bad* edit that turns code into snippet like you did here: https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/23586198 .. the OP is using a SASS code and it's very bad for the question to make it a snippet

Answer (score 0):

It is so easy!
Put the image inside an  tag or withing an  tag then add the attribute **download** and the images' URL withing that tag.
here is an example:

```html
<a href="https://www.publicdomainpictures.net/pictures/320000/nahled/background-image.png" download>
  <img src="https://www.publicdomainpictures.net/pictures/320000/nahled/background-image.png" alt="W3Schools" width="104" height="142">
</a>
```

image

Note: The download attribute is not supported in IE or Edge (prior version 18), or in Safari (prior version 10.1).